# AWS CLI parse error when listing more than two tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

**Why does this command work?:**

```json
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --profile ike \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value, Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value]' \
    --filter 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running' \
    --output table
```

**But not this command when I add a third tag?:**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --profile ike \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value, Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value], Tags[?Key==`Schedule`]|[0].Value]' \
    --filter 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running' \
    --output table
```

**Error output:**

> Bad value for --query Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value, Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value], Tags[?Key==`Schedule`]|[0].Value]: Unexpected token: ,: Parse error at column 140, token "," (COMMA), for expression:
> "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value, Tags[?Key==`Owner`]|[0].Value], Tags[?Key==`Schedule`]|[0].Value]"

Ii only works if I remove one of the tags.

I can change one of the TWO tags, and it works, but not with all three tags.

I'm still learning, obviously.

Comment: Please format your error message

Answer (score 2):

[`describe-instances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) accepts a valid [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) expression as a value for the parameter `--query`.

Your first expression is a valid JMESPath which I will paste here with indentations to make it more legible:

```
Reservations[].Instances[].[
   InstanceId,
   State.Name,
   InstanceType,
   PublicIpAddress,
   Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value,
   Tags[?Key==`Owner`] | [0].Value
]
```

It means:

1. Flatten all Instances (take every instance from every reservation and put them into a flat array).
2. Project each Instance to an array with the following members:

   1. `.InstanceId`
   2. `.State.Name`
   3. `.InstanceType`
   4. `.PublicIpAddress`
   5. Take the first object within the `.Tags` array which has a `{"key": "Name"}` element, and project its `.Value`
   6. Take the first object within the `.Tags` array which has a `{"key": "Owner"}` element, and project its `.Value`

Your second expression has an unbalanced bracket which you will easily find if you indent it properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time.  I see the errors now in my cli.